# OmniSharp server issue in VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I recently got VS Code and wanted to use C# but keep running into a problem which stops OmniSharp server from starting. Here is the OmniSharp Log:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 12/7/2021, 08:40:08
    Target: c:\Users\epik\Downloads\projects\hjkl

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\epik\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.12\.omnisharp\1.37.10\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 15908

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Interop.GetSetupConfiguration() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Interop.cs:line 20
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Providers.VisualStudioInstanceProvider.GetInstances() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Providers\VisualStudioInstanceProvider.cs:line 28
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator.GetInstances() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\MSBuildLocator.cs:line 235
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Extensions.GetBestInstance(IMSBuildLocator msbuildLocator, Version minimumMSBuildVersion, ILogger logger, Boolean& invalidVSFound, Boolean& vsWithoutSdkResolver) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Extensions.cs:line 109
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.Extensions.RegisterDefaultInstance(IMSBuildLocator msbuildLocator, ILogger logger, DotNetInfo dotNetInfo) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\MSBuild\Discovery\Extensions.cs:line 17
   at OmniSharp.CompositionHostBuilder.Build(String workingDirectory) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\CompositionHostBuilder.cs:line 71
   at OmniSharp.Stdio.Host..ctor(TextReader input, ISharedTextWriter writer, IOmniSharpEnvironment environment, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CompositionHostBuilder compositionHostBuilder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio\Host.cs:line 47
   at OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__1() in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver\Program.cs:line 74
   at OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start(Func`1 action) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\HostHelpers.cs:line 29
```

How do I fix it and what is causing it?

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1595 ? Particularly, [this comment](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1595#issuecomment-311665037)?

Comment: I don't have VS 2017.

Comment: Do you have _any_ version?

Comment: I have VS 2019 and it's a clean install.

Comment: Hmm.  Seeing that it's a clean install I wouldn't expect it to be causing an issue.  But you never know I guess.  I would try to repair VS 2019 and see what happens.

Comment: Alright, doing a repair right now.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing Visual Studio 2019 fixed it.